# sending emails to users registered to a django application

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

I am working on a django project. I the django project, I have a form for registering users to a service. Once the users are registered, I should be able to send promotional emails to them. For sending the emails itself, I am using [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/). THis is my code so far

**models.py**

```
class RegistrationModel(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import RegistrationModel

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationModel
        widgets = {
            'firstName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'lastName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),
            'address1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address1'}),
            'address2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address2'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City'}),
            'state': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'State'}),
            'pincode': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Pincode'}),
        }
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'pincode')
```

**settings.py**

```
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = 'I have added the api key here'
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = 'I have added the data center here'
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = 'I have added the audience id here'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import RegistrationModel
from .forms import RegistrationForm

import requests, json


MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = settings.MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID

api_url = f'https://{MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0'
members_endpoint = f'{api_url}/lists/{MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID}/members'

def subscribe(email):
    data = {
        "email_address": email,
        "status": 'subscribed'
    }

    r = requests.post(
        members_endpoint,
        auth=("", MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        data=json.dumps(data),
    )

    return r.status_code, r.json()

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            RF_qs = RegistraionModel.objects.filter(email=form.instance.email)
            if RF_qs.exists():
                messages.info(request, "You are already subscribed")
            else:
                subscribe(form.instance.email)
                form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))

    else:
        form = RegistraionForm()
        context = {'reg_form': form}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from sample_project import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('subscribe/', views.index, name='subscribe'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

But when I submit the form in the application, Nothing happens and the audience in mailchimp is not being populated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KeV42YaPes&t=254s) for creating the service

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send mailchimp a json payload, which also requires setting the content-type header and also the accepts header.  To do this, update the call in `subscribe`:

```
 r = requests.post(
        members_endpoint,
        auth=("", MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        json=data,
    )
 print(f'Response to mailchimp call [{r.status_code}]: {r.json()}')
```

Comment: There seems to be no change. I have also added the urlpatterns to the question. In case you need to look at that

Comment: You will want to try and capture the response to the request.post and log it to the console (either using logger or print).

Comment: Added in the example above.

Comment: nothing seems to be printed in the terminal. Could this be because the subscribe function is not being called? Or the url is not right or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that means that the form is not being found to be valid.  Is there a reason that the RegistrationForm is tied to the `VittalParivar`model and not the `RegistrationModel` model ?

Comment: No. I copied the code for the model and form from a different project I was working on for saving time. I forgot to change the name of the model while copying the code to stack overflow. Have edited the question now.

Comment: I tried printing the RF_qs after the form_valid condition and that prints out. So I guess the form is valid. The problem happens during the next condition in the index view